# Could you help identify this female 15 way, 4 mm pitch connector?

Tags: identification, connector

[image: Connector]

Connector is a female 15 way, 4 mm pitch. It appears to be similar to the Molex 0.156" connectors, but with some type of IDC connection for the incoming wires.

Comment: why did you post a picture of only the back of the connector?

Comment: Because that is the only picture I have. Otherwise I would have posted more pictures.

Comment: Can you provide more deatils? Out of what? Are you trying to replace it or ... ?